# Why does Datastax OpsCentre fail to read node information for some nodes in the cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

When I call the REST API method `/{cluster_id}/nodes`

Some of the nodes return contain complete information, and others do not. For example, this node returns info:

```
"node_ip": "10.20.155.122",
"network_interfaces": [
  "lo",
  "em1",
  "em2",
  "em3",
  "em4",
  "bond0",
  "bond1"
],
"ec2": {
  "instance-type": null,
  "placement": null,
  "ami-id": null,
  "instance-id": null
},
"node_version": {
  "search": null,
  "jobtracker": null,
  "tasktracker": null,
  "spark": {
    "master": false,
    "version": "1.1.0.2",
    "worker": true
  },
  "dse": "4.6.0",
  "cassandra": "2.0.11.83"
},
"dc": "Analytics",
"node_name": "BG1322",
"num_procs": 32,
"streaming": {

},
"token": "-1269200298813728863",
"data_held": 34651894.0,
"mode": "normal",
"rpc_ip": "10.20.155.122",
"partitions": {
  "saved_caches": "/dev/mapper/BG1322_applvol",
  "commitlog": "/dev/mapper/BG1322_applvol",
  "other": 
............ 
etc
```

And this one does not (node_name, data_held):

```
"node_ip": "10.20.155.123",
"network_interfaces": null,
"ec2": {

},
"node_version": {

},
"dc": "Analytics",
"node_name": null,
"num_procs": null,
"streaming": {

},
"token": "-4096905490099169213",
"data_held": null,
"mode": "unknown",
"rpc_ip": "10.20.155.123",
"partitions": {
  "saved_caches": null,
  "commitlog": null,
  "other": null,
  "data": null
},
"os": null,
"rack": "rack1",
"last_seen": 0
```

},
   {
    "load": null,
    "has_jna": false,
    "vnodes": true,
    "devices": {
      "saved_caches": null,
      "commitlog": null,
      "other": null,
      "data": null
    },
    "task_progress": {

```
},
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: node .155.123 was successfully added to the cluster ?

Comment: yes - they all work OK.